# How to obtain an expression for a complex differential equation

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential, separable-extension

Let us assume that we have the following expression:

$\frac{dx'(t,θ)}{dt} = Ax'(t,θ) + B(t)$

where $x'(t,θ) = \frac{\partial x(t,θ)}{\partial θ}$

in which $A$ is constant and $B(t)$ is a function of $t$. Furthermore, $θ$ is a parameter.

How can I solve this differential equation to obtain an expression for $x'(t)$ by using integration techniques? Is there a technique to make this differential equation separable?

I searched the bibliography but haven't managed to found something that can help me.

Every answer is greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to edit your question. Its really hard to read otherwise

Comment: @Smile I did fix the math format.

Comment: Use an integrating factor. You could also integrate with respect to $\theta$ first.

Comment: @mattos How can I use an integrating factor if the right-hand side expression is not separable?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x=x(t,\theta)$ depends on both $t$ and $\theta$, and we want to find $x'(t,\theta)=\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}.$ Let $y=x'(x,t)$, so the equation becomes

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=Ay+B(t)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}-Ay=B(t)$$

and multiplying by the integrating factor $e^{-At}$ gives

$$e^{-At}\frac{dy}{dt}-Ae^{-At}y=e^{-At}B(t)$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(ye^{-At}\right)=e^{-At}B(t)$$
$$ye^{-At}=\int e^{-At}B(t)dt+C$$
$$y=e^{At}\int e^{-At}B(t)dt+Ce^{At}$$
$$\implies x'=e^{At}\int e^{-At}B(t)dt+Ce^{At}$$

for an arbitrary constant $C$

Comment: Ares, thank you for your comment. It would be very useful formula for my experiments.

Comment: You're very welcome! :-)